# Setting Environment variables for using Windows MAVEN for ANdroid

Tags: android, maven, maven-plugin

I want to use maven for Android. what `Environment Variables` should i set, such `mvn command` work. First i setted `JAVA_HOME to jdk folder` and `ANDROID_HOME to ANdroid-sdk folder` using set command.

but still `mvn command`  not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you have not updated `PATH` variable with the location of `mvn.bat`.

For example

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin
```